# What am I doing wrong in declaring a predicate for use with a DCG in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg

I'm using the following to check if a string is valid for use with my grammar:

```
id(ID) :-
    atom_chars(ID, [H|T]),
    is_alpha(H),
    ensure_valid_char(T).

ensure_valid_char([H|T]) :-
    H == '_';
    is_alpha(H);
    atom_number(H, _),
    ensure_valid_char(T).
```

It basically just checks that it starts with an alphabetic character, and after that it can be alphanumeric or an underscore.

I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work with my DCG/grammar though.

This is its current structure where the predicate would be used:

```
typeID(Result) --> ['int'], id(ID), {
    Result = ['int', ID]
}.
```

Where basically I'm saying a `typeID` is an integer type declaration followed by an identifier (`int foo` would be an example), and then I format it into a list and "give it back".

But in this case it's saying "id" is an undefined predicate. How do I use it so that I'm still able to access what ID holds to be able to format it, and still ensure that it's an ID using the predicate?

If I try:

```
id(ID) --> {
    atom_chars(ID, [H|T]),
    is_alpha(H),
    ensure_valid_char(T),
    ID = ID 
}.
```

I get the error that:

```
atom_chars/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use more readable names. The Prolog convention is to use **underscores** for readability.

This `is_because_using_underscores_makes_even_long_names_readable`, `butUsingMixedCapsDoesNotAndMakesYourCodeAsUnreadableAsJava`.

Second, please avoid unnecessary goals. A goal like `ID=ID` always holds, so you can as well remove it.

Third, a common pattern when describing the longest match in DCGs is to use clauses like the following:

```
symbol([A|As]) -->
    [A],
    { memberchk(A, "+/-*><=") ; code_type(A, alpha) },
    symbolr(As).

symbolr([A|As]) -->
    [A],
    { memberchk(A, "+/-*><=") ; code_type(A, alnum) },
    symbolr(As).
symbolr([]) --> [].
```

You can use this in a DCG like this:

```
id(Atom) --> symbol(Codes), { atom_codes(Atom, Cs) }
```

The longest match of `symbol//1` will be the first solution.

All of this requires that you have the Prolog flag `double_quotes` set to `codes`.

Answer (score 0):

semicolon has higher precedence than comma

```
?- (N=(',') ; N=(';')), current_op(P,T,N).
N =  (','),
P = 1000,
T = xfy ;
N =  (;),
P = 1100,
T = xfy.
```

then ensure_valid_char/1 doesn't have the structure you expect. It should be

```
ensure_valid_char([H|T]) :-
    ( H == '_' ;
      is_alpha(H) ;
      atom_number(H, _)  % ugly 
    ),
    ensure_valid_char(T).
```

and a simpler issue: you're missing the base case of the recursion

```
ensure_valid_char([]).
```